# How to open bootstrap model on ajax success in an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I want to open bootstrap model on success of ajax function in an iframe.

I've tried using:

```
$('#mapDiv').modal('show');   
jQuery("#mapDiv").modal('show');
```

Both are not working in an iframe.
Please do excuse if it is not that much worthy to ask.
I can able to that using

```
$('#mapDiv').show();
```

But I need to write close() function. I want a solution from bootstrap side.
If not I go with JQuery.
Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0):

As you are aware that `jquery` library functions are accessible only for the page inside the frame, so you can close it using `parent.hide()` function ,

```
parent.$('#mapDiv').modal('hide');
```

from your `iframe`